# Judiciary/juridicial labour

Tags: word-choice

I know that uauslly we do not think of judging as 'labour', but if we wished to do so, would you prefer saying "judiciary labour" or rather "juridicial labour"? Do both of them sound just too odd?

Comment: I'd call it "judging", or if you really want to include the word labor, then "judicial labor"; but *labor* has overtones of manual labor, and law is not a physical profession. It causes cognitive dissonance.

Comment: I am well aware of this cognitive dissonance, this is exactly what I want to achieve by thinking of judging in terms of 'labour'. Should it then be 'judging labour'? Does it sound better than the other two options?

Comment: Intellectual labor can still be treated as labor, and it is valid and important so to treat it in certain contexts, e.g., where professors are unionized, and where judges may protest their case-loads. And then, of course, there is [Peter Cook's immortal comparison of judging with mining](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bb0TpcoXtZs). Of the two adjectives, I'd favor *juridical (with only 2 i's, though).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the two are not exactly the same.

Judiciary labour means labour pertaining to *the* established judiciary, whereas juridicial labour is simply labour relating to the process or administration of law.

It depends entirely on what you're trying to say.